# Check if a user can read a specified File

Tags: 2010, permissions, security, user, file

I'm working with SharePoint Client API 2010 for a .Net application.
I want to check if the current user (or a specified user) can read a specified File?
This user could also be in a SP Group or in a LDAP Group.

My current approach would be to request the file and wait for an exception that may be raised if a user doesnt have the required permission:

```
        string SiteUrl = "https://myintraneturl/";
        ClientContext clientContextSP = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
        Web site = clientContextSP.Web;

        File file = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/someworkingfilepath/somefile.txt");


        var listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
        clientContextSP.Load(listItem, items => items.EffectiveBasePermissions);

        try {

        clientContextSP.ExecuteQuery();

        var test = listItem.EffectiveBasePermissions.Has(PermissionKind.Open);

        } catch...
```

This approach doesnt seem to be right to me. I would control the program flow by exception and that is not what seems to be desirable.

Do you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with:

```
    public bool DoesUserHavePermission(string RelativeUrl)
    {
        File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(RelativeUrl);
        clientContext.Load(file, item => item.Exists);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        return file.Exists;
    }
```

It's return false when the file doesn't exists but also when the current user doesn't have the permission to see this file !